# ie9 default search provider corrupted

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, bing

I got the pop-up from ie9 saying the default search provider has been corrupted everytime i open it, and ie9 will direct me to "manage add-ons" window, and actually the Bing search is there!

I guess this is because I deleted the registry key for bing frome the regedit:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Internet Explorer -> SearchScopes

Now if i create another user account for my computer and open ie9, everything goes fine and happy. Sadly I cannot export the key from the new user account and import it in my current account.

Did anyone knows how to deal with this situation?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional (64 bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one have any guess? Finally I solved it by copying the registry key from a newly created account of my computer and then add them in the current user account. 
To do this you'll need the read/write rights to regedit.

Answer (score 0):

Also found big problems on old machine. Here is fresh list.
FaviconPath shoud be changed - it is a local path to downloaded icons (4 in my case).
Default in this export was Google.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes]
"DefaultScope"="{FA07CFB2-243B-4E44-9F3C-7BEDE0D9DEFF}"
"DownloadRetries"=dword:00000005
"Version"=dword:00000005

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{3ED1B5E1-8E9D-4EF2-8024-0AB69DCCAB86}]
"DisplayName"="GraysOnline"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWiaTt"
"FaviconURL"="http://images.graysonline.com/favicon.ico"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="http://www.graysonline.com/Search.aspx?q={searchTerms}"
"SuggestionsURL"="http://www.graysonline.com/OpenSearch/SuggestionsXml.aspx?q={searchTerms}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{77D32E17-3DF9-4314-AC2B-CAE24A33D76C}]
"Codepage"=dword:0000fde9
"DisplayName"="The-Arena"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWidzo"
"FaviconURL"="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/favicon.ico"
"SuggestionsURL_JSON"="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/autosuggestionjson.aspx?sc={searchTerms}"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/default.aspx?sc={searchTerms}"
"SuggestionsURL"="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/autosuggestion.aspx?sc={searchTerms}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{7A65992E-52A6-4C55-AA2E-7FE3E11500D4}]
"DisplayName"="Wikipedia (en)"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWihZ8"
"FaviconPath"="...\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Services\\search_{7A65992E-52A6-4C55-AA2E-7FE3E11500D4}.ico"
"FaviconURL"="http://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico"
"SuggestionsURL_JSON"="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search={searchTerms}&namespace=0"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search={searchTerms}"
"SuggestionsURL"="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&search={searchTerms}&namespace=0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{9A5AFB82-F365-4FB6-839F-76EB88058B29}]
"DisplayName"="Yahoo!"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWilsN"
"FaviconPath"="...\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Services\\search_{9A5AFB82-F365-4FB6-839F-76EB88058B29}.ico"
"FaviconURL"="http://search.yahoo.com/favicon.ico"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="https://search.yahoo.com/search?p={searchTerms}&b={startPage?}&fr=ie8"
"SuggestionsURL"="https://ie.search.yahoo.com/os?appid=ie8&command={searchTerms}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{C07B5DB4-5C3F-45A0-A90D-9E969E1C2FC2}]
"Codepage"=dword:0000fde9
"DisplayName"="Bing"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWilsP"
"FaviconURL"="http://www.bing.com/favicon.ico"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;src=IE-SearchBox&amp;FORM=IESR02"
"SuggestionsURL"="http://api.bing.com/qsml.aspx?query={searchTerms}&maxwidth={ie:maxWidth}&rowheight={ie:rowHeight}&sectionHeight={ie:sectionHeight}&FORM=IESS02&market={language}"
"NTURL"="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IENTSR"
"NTTopResultURL"="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IENTTR"
"NTSuggestionsURL"="http://api.bing.com/qsml.aspx?query={searchTerms}&market={language}&maxwidth={ie:maxWidth}&rowheight={ie:rowHeight}&sectionHeight={ie:sectionHeight}&FORM=IENTSS"
"NTLogoPath"="...\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Services\\"
"NTLogoURL"="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=403856&language={language}&scale={scalelevel}&contrast={contrast}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{CA4C6196-3C71-4BF7-AF8B-DEE226259F52}]
"DisplayName"="eBay"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWihZ7"
"FaviconURL"="http://ie8.ebay.com/resources/images/favicon.ico"
"SuggestionsURL_JSON"="http://sug.ebay.com/?q={searchTerms}&c=0"
"PreviewURL"="http://ie8.ebay.com/accelerator/search/?q={searchTerms}&s=0"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-43047-14818-1/4?satitle={searchTerms}"
"SuggestionsURL"="http://ie8.ebay.com/suggest/visual/?q={searchTerms}&s=0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{D978B8FD-BE25-410D-BD3C-0BFD40B8C902}]
"DisplayName"="Youtube"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWiaTu"
"FaviconPath"="...\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Services\\search_{D978B8FD-BE25-410D-BD3C-0BFD40B8C902}.ico"
"FaviconURL"="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vfl1123.ico"
"URL"="http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={searchTerms}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{FA07CFB2-243B-4E44-9F3C-7BEDE0D9DEFF}]
"DisplayName"="Google"
"OSDFileURL"="https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWilsM"
"FaviconPath"="...\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Services\\search_{FA07CFB2-243B-4E44-9F3C-7BEDE0D9DEFF}.ico"
"FaviconURL"="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"URL"="https://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:{language}:{referrer:source}&ie={inputEncoding?}&oe={outputEncoding?}"
"SuggestionsURL"="https://www.google.com/complete/search?q={searchTerms}&client=ie8&mw={ie:maxWidth}&sh={ie:sectionHeight}&rh={ie:rowHeight}&inputencoding={inputEncoding}&outputencoding={outputEncoding}"
```

Source data and links:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWiaTt
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>GraysOnline</ShortName>
<Description>Find a great deal with GraysOnline</Description>
<Url type="text/html" template="http://www.graysonline.com/Search.aspx?q={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+xml" template="http://www.graysonline.com/OpenSearch/SuggestionsXml.aspx?q={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/rss+xml" template="http://www.graysonline.com/OpenSearch/SuggestionsRss.ashx?q={searchTerms}" />
<Image height="16" width="16" type="image/icon">http://images.graysonline.com/favicon.ico</Image>
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWidzo
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>The-Arena</ShortName>
<Description>The-Arena</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding><Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">http://www.the-arena.co.uk/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/default.aspx?sc={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/rss+xml" method="get" template="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/arena_rss.aspx?sc={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+xml" template="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/autosuggestion.aspx?sc={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="http://www.the-arena.co.uk/autosuggestionjson.aspx?sc={searchTerms}" />
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWihZ8
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>Wikipedia (en)</ShortName>
<Description>Wikipedia (en)</Description><Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">http://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&amp;search={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="get" template="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&amp;search={searchTerms}&amp;namespace=0" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+xml" method="get" template="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&amp;format=xml&amp;search={searchTerms}&amp;namespace=0" /><moz:SearchForm>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search</moz:SearchForm>
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWilsN
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>Yahoo!</ShortName>
<Url type="text/html" template="https://search.yahoo.com/search?p={searchTerms}&amp;b={startPage?}&amp;fr=ie8" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+xml" template="https://ie.search.yahoo.com/os?appid=ie8&amp;command={searchTerms}" /><Image height="16" width="16" type="image/icon">http://search.yahoo.com/favicon.ico</Image>
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWilsP
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2008/" xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>Bing</ShortName><Tags>Bing</Tags>
<Description>Bing Search by Microsoft.</Description><Contact>msosa@microsoft.com</Contact>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding><SyndicationRight>limited</SyndicationRight><Image type="image/x-icon" height="16" width="16">http://www.bing.com/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" template="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;amp;src=IE-SearchBox&amp;amp;FORM=IESR02" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+xml" template="http://api.bing.com/qsml.aspx?query={searchTerms}&amp;maxwidth={ie:maxWidth}&amp;rowheight={ie:rowHeight}&amp;sectionHeight={ie:sectionHeight}&amp;FORM=IESS02&amp;market={language}" /><ie:TopResult type="text/html" template="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;src=IE-TopResult&amp;FORM=IETR02" /><ie:NTSearchResult type="text/html" template="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;src=IE-SearchBox&amp;FORM=IENTSR" /><ie:NTTopResult type="text/html" template="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;src=IE-SearchBox&amp;FORM=IENTTR" /><ie:NTSearchSuggestion type="application/x-suggestions+xml" template="http://api.bing.com/qsml.aspx?query={searchTerms}&amp;market={language}&amp;maxwidth={ie:maxWidth}&amp;rowheight={ie:rowHeight}&amp;sectionHeight={ie:sectionHeight}&amp;FORM=IENTSS" /><ie:NTLogo type="image/png">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=403856&amp;language={language}&amp;scale={scalelevel}&amp;contrast={contrast}</ie:NTLogo>
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWihZ7
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2008/" xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>eBay</ShortName>
<Description>eBay - The World's Online Marketplace</Description><Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">http://ie8.ebay.com/resources/images/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-43047-14818-1/4?satitle={searchTerms}" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="get" template="http://sug.ebay.com/?q={searchTerms}&amp;c=0" />
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+xml" method="get" template="http://ie8.ebay.com/suggest/visual/?q={searchTerms}&amp;s=0" /><ie:PreviewUrl type="text/html" template="http://ie8.ebay.com/accelerator/search/?q={searchTerms}&amp;s=0" />
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWiaTu
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>Youtube</ShortName>
<Url type="text/html" template="http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={searchTerms}" /><Image height="16" width="16" type="image/icon">http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-vfl1123.ico</Image>
</OpenSearchDescription>

https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWilsM
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2008/" xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>Google</ShortName>
<Description>Google Search</Description>
<Url xmlns:referrer="http://a9.com/-/opensearch/extensions/referrer/1.0/" type="text/html" template="https://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;sourceid=ie7&amp;rls=com.microsoft:{language}:{referrer:source}&amp;ie={inputEncoding?}&amp;oe={outputEncoding?}" />
<Url rel="suggestions" type="application/x-suggestions+xml" template="https://www.google.com/complete/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;client=ie8&amp;mw={ie:maxWidth}&amp;sh={ie:sectionHeight}&amp;rh={ie:rowHeight}&amp;inputencoding={inputEncoding}&amp;outputencoding={outputEncoding}" /><Image height="16" width="16" type="image/icon">https://www.google.com/favicon.ico</Image></OpenSearchDescription>
```